# Array intersection of two large files

Tags: php, arrays

I have two files, each having the following structure:

```
Gjdfnsdmfn141kj4
Fsndfdksjf1lkfjf
fjdksfn2m1kd1jk2
cmvlkm2kljo4jojj
```

Which means rows line by line of strings with the same length. Both files weight about 1GB, which means ~40mln of rows.

I want to count the number of rows that exist in both files.

First problems that occured are memory exceeds, then buffering two files at once, etc. My idea is to compare single chunks of data, let's say 100k lines, then save the intersection to output array, and erase temp arrays, etc.

The (pseudo) code I managed to write is something like that:

```
$output = [];

$first = [];
$fh1 = fopen("file1.txt", "r");
while (!feof($fh1)) {
   $first[] = fgets($fh1);
}

$chunk = 100000;

$fh2 = fopen("file2.txt", "r");
while (!feof($fh1)) {
   $count = 0;
   $lines = [];
   while(!feof($fh1) && (++count == $chunk)) {
      $lines[] = fgets($fh1);
   }
   intersection($fh1, $lines, $first);
}

function intersection($fh1, $lines, $first) {
   $output = array_merge($output, array_intersect($lines, $first));
}
```

But it's kind of slow, seems to always result with empty `array_intersect` result, and to work only if one of the files is significantly smaller.

How do I do this in a better way?

Comment: If on Linux you can use `exec()` and `comm file1.txt file2.txt` or `fgrep -xf file1.txt file2.txt`

Comment: `comm` requires the files to be sorted.

Comment: Your chunking algorithm won't work if the matching lines in the two files are in different chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an [external sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) algorithm to sort the files first. PHP probably isn't ideal for this, so an existing tool would be better, but Google seems to have some examples of people having done it before in PHP too.

Then you can open both (sorted) files and move through them together looking for matches. You just move forward in one until you have a row which would go after the current row in the other, and then switch (outputting if the two show the same row). That way you get all the matches but only need to pass over each file once.